# AWS Cognito remembering social user

Tags: amazon-web-services, facebook-login, google-signin, amazon-cognito

**My use case**

When my users login through google/facebook, I want to remember them. I think it is a very simple use case.

How can I store google/facebook user's identification details (like cognito created unique identifiers / userids given by social IdPs)

If I cant store social user's identity using aws cognito, I think cognito is not necessary.

I've searched for a while and finally posting this question.
There is no proper documentation available on this topic.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html

The IdP's unique identifier for the user (subject) in the ID token is `sub`.

http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#StandardClaims